# Better way to find sums in a grid in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an app with a 6x7 grid that lets the user input values. After each value is obtained the app checks to find if any of the consecutive values create a sum of ten and executes further code (which I have working well for the 4 test cases I've written). So far I've been writing if statements similar to the below:

```
func findTens() {
        if (rowOneColumnOnePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnTwoPlaceHolderValue) == 10 {
            //code to execute
        } else if (rowOneColumnOnePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnTwoPlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnThreePlaceHolderValue) == 10 {
            //code to execute
        } else if (rowOneColumnOnePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnTwoPlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnThreePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnFourPlaceHolderValue) == 10 {
            //code to execute
        } else if (rowOneColumnOnePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnTwoPlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnThreePlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnFourPlaceHolderValue + rowOneColumnFivePlaceHolderValue) == 10 {
            //code to execute
}
```

That's not quite halfway through row one, and it will end up being a very large set of if statements (231 if I'm calculating correctly, since a single 7 column row would be 1,2-1,2,3-...-2,3-2,3,4-...-67 so 21 possibilities per row). I think there must be a more concise way of doing it but I've struggled to find something better.

I've thought about using an array of each of the rowXColumnYPlaceHolderValue variables similar to the below:

```
let rowOnePlaceHolderArray = [rowOneColumnOnePlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnTwoPlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnThreePlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnFourPlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnFivePlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnSixPlaceHolderValue, rowOneColumnSevenPlaceHolderValue]
        for row in rowOnePlaceHolderArray {
           //compare each element of the array here, 126 comparisons 
        }
```

But I'm struggling to find a next step to that approach, in addition to the fact that those array elements then apparently because copies and not references to the original array anymore...

I've been lucky enough to find some fairly clever solutions to some of the other issues I've come across for the app, but this one has given me trouble for about a week now so I wanted to ask for help to see what ideas I might be missing. It's possible that there will not be another approach that is significantly better than the 231 if statement approach, which will be ok. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Definitely use arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea (off the top of my head; I have not bothered to optimize). I'll assume that your goal is:

> Given an array of Int, find the first consecutive elements that sum to a given Int total.

Your use of "10" as a target total is just a special case of that.

So I'll look for consecutive elements that sum to a given total, and if I find them, I'll return their range within the original array. If I don't find any, I'll return `nil`.

Here we go:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func rangeOfSum(_ sum: Int) -> Range<Int>? {
        newstart:
        for start in 0..<count-1 {
            let slice = dropFirst(start)
            for n in 2...slice.count {
                let total = slice.prefix(n).reduce(0,+)
                if total == sum {
                    return start..<(start+n)
                }
                if total > sum {
                    continue newstart
                }
                if n == slice.count && total < sum {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
[1, 8, 6, 2, 8, 4].rangeOfSum(10) // 3..<5, i.e. 2,8
[1, 8, 1, 2, 8, 4].rangeOfSum(10) // 0..<3, i.e. 1,8,1
[1, 8, 3, 2, 9, 4].rangeOfSum(10) // nil
```

Okay, so now that we've got that, extracting each possible row or column from the grid (or whatever the purpose of the game is) is left as an exercise for the reader.